# Why my kube config does not work?Error: DatabaseAccountNotFoundError: Failed to find the account within the internal database

Tags: kubernetes

I created a cluster (Civo)
[image]

downloaded config and added COPY + paste to my `~.kube/config`

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

shows

```
CURRENT   NAME              CLUSTER           AUTHINFO          NAMESPACE
*         serverless-apps   serverless-apps   serverless-apps
```

If I try civo cli

```
civo kubernetes ls
Error: DatabaseAccountNotFoundError: Failed to find the account within the internal database
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you really need `civo Kubernetes ls`, as you already have the kubeconfig which is enough for Kubernetes auth.

you can simple try `kubectl get node` it should work.

or

```
civo kubernetes config kube_demo --save --merge

#Merged with main kubernetes config: ~/.kube/config

Access your cluster with:
kubectl config use-context kube_demo
kubectl get node
```

[kubernetes-cluster-administration-using-civo-cli](https://www.civo.com/learn/kubernetes-cluster-administration-using-civo-cli)

Answer (score 0):

The response from the server gives you the indication.
Your provided API key isn't valid

Your CIVO token is stored in ~/.civo.json

If I "break" my key I receive the same error

`civo Kubernetes ls` requires civo auth

`kubectl` requires your Kubernetes credentials instead

Check your .civo.json